# Python return do not exists based on 2 columns on separate dataframes

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 dataframes

```
df1
Report Period    170 non-null object
Links            170 non-null object
```

and

```
df2 
reportmonth    1965 non-null object
links          1965 non-null object
```

I want to compare df1 to df2 on `['reportmonth'] = ['Report Period'] and ['Links'] = ['links']`
I want to return all records from df1 that dont exists in df2 based on condition above

Something to the effect of

```
full_table[full_table['Links'] not in (dfold['links']) and full_table['Report Period'] not in (dfold['reportmonth'])]
```

but that code gave me error

```
'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: Compare step - set(df1['reportmonth'].difference(set(df2['reportmonth']))

Now reportmonth values that are in df1 but df2 are the output.

Return all records(2nd step) - df1.loc[df1['reportmonth'].isin or in list(output values from above)

Comment: set(df1['Report Period'].difference(set(df2['reportmonth'])))

Comment: got error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'difference'

Comment: Ok i figured out half of my condition with links column how about my ['report period'] column

Comment: First condition is-->

    df1[~df1.Links.isin(df2['links'])]

Comment: So, the issue resolved?